# Restoring using ROM Manager

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, restore, rom-manager

I created a backup file successfully using ROM Manager and saved it on my PC. I lost all my data on mobile and now I want to restore my mobile using the backup file I created.

I copied the backup file to mobile but in ROM Manager its still showing 0 backups. Where to copy the backup files in phone so that ROM Manager can find it?

Comment: What device and recovery are you using?

Comment: Its MTK based device, I am using latest ROM Manager.